# Processing 3: NullPointerException using PTreeMappa

Tags: processing, treemap

I'm using Processing 3 for generating a Treemap.I installed gicentreUtils and placed TreeMappa file in the library folder of Processing. I'm getting nullPointerException in line:

```
pTreeMappa = new PTreeMappa(this).
```

The full code can be found in this
[link](http://staff.city.ac.uk/~jwo/processing/treeMappa/)

Can someone please let me know how to resolve this error.

Thanks

Comment: The link doesn't seem to work (perhaps it works only on the City University intranet ?)

Comment: Sorry, it's working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the TreeMapa library hasn't been updated in a few years and internally it may use some Processing code that changed from version 2.x to 3.x (like windows/frames/etc.) which is why the error might occur.

I advise using TreeMapa with Processing 2.2.1 available on the [Processing Downloads](http://processing.org/download/) page

Comment: Does the input csv file for PTreeMappa contains only numbers? Is it possible to work with csv file containing strings as well?

Comment: I haven't heard of TreeMappa until you've mentioned in the question, so definitely not an expert in the topic, however, if you scroll down on the same page, you can see .xml data data being loaded so perhaps there is. I'd go through the provided documentations,[javadocs](http://staff.city.ac.uk/~jwo/treemappa/software/api/index.html) and library examples first.